# How to make an image responsive height?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbjXKg)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://rochester.motorcitynewengland.com/img/cars/kia-forte.jpg" alt="2015 Kia Forte" title="2015 Kia Forte" class="img-responsive">
    </div>  

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://rochester.motorcitynewengland.com/img/cars/chrysler-300C-min.jpg" alt="2015 Kia Forte" title="2015 Kia Forte" class="img-responsive">
    </div>  


    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://rochester.motorcitynewengland.com/img/cars/dodge-dart-min.jpg" alt="2015 Kia Forte" title="2015 Kia Forte" class="img-responsive">
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
img{
    max-height: 355px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The problem is that if you resize the window ... the first image is taller than the other two.
How can I always keep the same height to all 3 pictures?but the images to be responsive both height and width.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about `.img-responsive {
    width: auto;
    height: 355px;
}`

Comment: Well you cannot make an image responsive ( equal height or equal width ) using both height and width inside the image tag. You have to choose 1 property, either width or height. Another option is to use the answer provided by @Dhaval

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do to mantain the height is to set your images as fluid, but mantain their aspect ratio; there are several tutorials about how to do that, e.g. http://www.goldenapplewebdesign.com/responsive-aspect-ratios-with-pure-css/ or https://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/

the cons is that the images will get cropped if their aspect ratio is not 16:9

Answer (score 0):

So what i would suggest is to make 3 css class for 3 div.

```
<div class="col-md-4 xyz1></div>
<div class="col-md-4 xyz2"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 xyz3"></div>
```

in css you can set background of the div to be you image.

```
.xyz1{
 background : url(yourUrl);
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

you can use background image for each div instead

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 img1 img">
  </div>  

  <div class="col-md-4 img2 img">
  </div>  

  <div class="col-md-4 img3 img">
  </div>  

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img1{
  background:url(http://rochester.motorcitynewengland.com/img/cars/kia-forte.jpg);

}
.img2{
  background:url(http://rochester.motorcitynewengland.com/img/cars/chrysler-300C-min.jpg);

}
.img3{
  background:url(http://rochester.motorcitynewengland.com/img/cars/dodge-dart-min.jpg);

}

.img{
    height: 355px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;

}
```

[**working demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbjXjX)

Comment: yes but I do not want to use the background-image can not be otherwise?

Comment: if you want to use img then you should use the same size proportion for all images.

Answer (score 0):

Put each image in a div class, and make in css a max-height:"...px" ans set width to auto